# Convert all video files in a folder to images per frame using ffmpeg iteratively

Tags: bash, ffmpeg

I use `ffmpeg -i FILE_NAME -vf fps=1/1 FILE_NAME%05d.jpg -hide_banner` to convert a single file to several images which keep the file name followed by 5 zeros, a counter and then ends with a .jpg.

How do I do the same thing to all, let's say .mov, files in a single folder, keeping the file naming convention the same?

I understand there will be a loop and a `*.mov` to select all files in the folder but I'm lost in the naming convention part.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for FILE_NAME in *.mov
do
    ffmpeg -i "$FILE_NAME" -vf fps=1/1 "$FILE_NAME"%05d.jpg -hide_banner
done
```

This will result in output files named like `something.mov00000.jpg`. To remove the `.mov` or any other file type ending you can do

```
for FILE_NAME in *.mov
do
    ffmpeg -i "$FILE_NAME" -vf fps=1/1 "${FILE_NAME%.*}"%05d.jpg -hide_banner
done
```